# Subset a list with an index

Tags: python, list, amazon-s3

I have a list `my_list`

I am looking to return a new list of everything including and after `'mythird.csv'`.

```
my_list = ['myfirst.csv','mysecond.csv','mythird.csv','myfourth.csv']
my_index = 'mythird.csv'
```

I want my result to look like this:

```
my_result = ['mythird.csv','myfourth.csv']
```

For context, I am working with an s3 bucket and my list of csvs comes from:

```
import s3fs
fs = s3fs.S3FileSystem(key, secret)
bucket = "s3://mybucket"
my_list = fs.ls(bucket)
```

Comment: `my_list[my_list.index('mythird.csv'):]`

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists

Comment: are you trying to do this by position or given an arbitrary object? If by position, simply use slicing `my_list[2:]` which will give you the third item all the way until the end. If by some arbitrary object, `my_list[my_list.index(foo):]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split the list with the index:

```
my_list = ['myfirst.csv','mysecond.csv','mythird.csv','myfourth.csv']
my_index = 'mythird.csv'

my_result = my_list[my_list.index(my_index):]
```